# Adobe Commerce Annual License Cost

Tags: license

I know Adobe Commerce charges us annual license cost based on our GMV. Is there any way that we find a software vendor implementing Magento for us but we can bypass the annual license cost? Thanks.

Comment: "bypass the annual license cost" you do realize that's illegal? someone has to pay the licence cost if you're using commerce.

Answer (score 0):

No . Adobe Commerce is a commercial piece of software.

If you don't have the budget, I'd highly recommend Magento Open Source as it's basically the same with a few less features. If you're on a budget, you most likely won't be able to justify the cost of Commerce anyways.